# Flaw in my logic - Java

Tags: java, logic

I have to write a program that uses arrays to represent 100 students either opening or closing 100 lockers. starting from student 1, every student has to change the lockers position (i.e open if closed, close if opened) if their student number is a factor of the locker number. for example student 3 would change the positions of lockers 3, 6, 9, etc...

```
public class LockerFun {
public static void main (String[] args) {
  int[] lockers = new int[101];
  int[] students = new int[101];
  for (int i = 1; i < lockers.length; i++) {
     lockers[i] = 1;
  }
  for (int i = 1; i < students.length; i++) {
     System.out.print( i + " ");
     for (int j = 1; j < lockers.length; j++) {
        if (j % i == 0) {
           lockers[i] *= -1;
        }
     }
  }
  System.out.println();
  for (int i = 1; i < lockers.length; i++) {
     if (lockers[i] == -1) {
        System.out.print( "O ");
     }
     else {
        System.out.print( "X ");
     }
    }
  }
}
// 1 = closed, -1 = open
```

Somewhere there is a flaw in my logic because the final result is supposed to be every locker number that is a perfect square is opened, the rest are closed. Where do I go wrong? my friend said something about using boolean values for the lockers but I dont know how that would change the outcome

Comment: In java, array indexes starts from `0` to `N-1`. Why do you have your array of size `101`? That means that is 101 placeholders created in memory. Your `for` loop must start from `0` to ` < lockers.length`. and your lockers must be `boolean[] lockers = new boolean[100]`. That way you can do `if (lockers[i])) { //Locker is closed`.

Comment: Why do you have a `students` array at all? All you do is use its length. Why not just have a number of students?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take care with a few things:

1. The index you are using for your lockers array is the wrong one and your main error.
2. You should use a boolean to mark the state, as your friend said; the result will be the same, but the code will be cleaner and the memory footprint smaller (from 101 int values to 101 boolean).
3. You can use an array from 0 to 99, but you will need to correct the indexes you are using for arrays. If you are only not using the "0" index you can leave it like you have it now, for the sake of been easy to understand, I kept your indexing.
4. You should use a formatting method for your output to align the indexes with the values.
5. You are not using the students array, only the number of students, so you can remove it from your code and introduce only a variable or constant, you will save memory space (from 10 int values to 1).

Your code corrected is the following one:

```
public class LockerFun {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int numberOfStudents = 100;
        boolean[] lockers = new boolean[101];

        for (int i = 1; i < lockers.length; i++)
            lockers[i] = true;

        for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfStudents; i++) {
            System.out.print(String.format("%4d", i));
            for (int j = 1; j < lockers.length; j++) {
                if (j % i == 0) {
                    lockers[j] = !lockers[j];
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println();
        for (int i = 1; i < lockers.length; i++) {
            if (lockers[i])
                System.out.print(String.format("%4s", "X"));
            else
                System.out.print(String.format("%4s", "O"));
        }
    }
}
```

I hope that helps you.

Answer (score 1):

One mistake - in your inner loop, you change `lockers[i]` instead of `lockers[j]`

But why don't you make the inner `for` loop only the specific numbers, `3, 6, 9...`? It'll make the code simpler, e.g.

```
 for (int j = i; j < lockers.length; j += i) {
     lockers[j] *= -1;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your method that opens and closes lockers:

```
for (int i = 1; i < students.length; i++) {
    System.out.print( i + " ");
    for (int j = 1; j < lockers.length; j++) {
        if (j % i == 0) {
            lockers[i] *= -1;
        }
    }
}
```

This line needs to reference the locker index, not the student, i.e.

```
lockers[j] *= -1;
```